# Android Studio error when trying to generate release signed APK, but let you build debug APK

Tags: android, android-studio

When I use the option "Build APK" in Android Studio 2.3.3 it generates a debug APK without issue, but when I try to generate a signed APK, an error appears:

> Generate Signed APK: Errors while building APK. You can find the
>   errors in the 'Messages' view.

And in the 'Messages" view:

> Error: Expected resource of type string [ResourceType]

It's doesn't seem to be a problem of the keystore or the signature, because it leads me to a line of the code, which is:

```
String color = getResources().getString(VarGlobales.color4).substring(3);
```

VarGlobales is just a class I created to define global variables, and of course it's imported correctly. `VarGlobales.color4` is underlined, and when I hover, it says:

> Expected resource of type string [less...] (Ctrl+F1)  This inspection
>   looks at Android API calls that have been annotated with various
>   support annotations (such as RequiresPermission or UiThread) and flags
>   any calls that are not using the API correctly as specified by the
>   annotations.  Examples of errors flagged by this inspection: Passing
>   the wrong type of resource integer (such as R.string) to an API that
>   expects a different type (such as R.dimen). Forgetting to invoke the
>   overridden method (via super) in methods that require it Calling a
>   method that requires a permission without having declared that
>   permission in the manifest Passing a resource color reference to a
>   method which expects an RGB integer value. ...and many more.  For more
>   information, see the documentation at
>   http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/annotations.html

`VarGlobales.color4` is an Integer so, as far as I know, it should not give any error because `getString()` needs an Integer ID as a parameter. Doesn't the definition have the value I expected? It's like this:

```
// In VarGlobales class
public static int color4 = R.color.teal4;
```

`R.color.teal4` was defined in `colors.xml` this way:

```
// In colors.xml
<color name="teal4">#00796B</color>
```

What's odd is that it doesn't give any error when building a debug APK so at first it shouldn't be a code problem.

Comment: It must be `getResources().getColor(VarGlobales.color4)`. But this is deprecated. So you need to use `ContextCompact.getColor(this ,VarGlobales.color4)`

Comment: The app uses API level 14 (and it's necessary that it could run in Android 4), so I cannot use ContextCompat

Comment: This will also work `getResources().getColor(VarGlobales.color4)`.Its deprecated not banned.

Comment: Does it work if you use the R.id directly?